# How in RSpec to test blank/empty string for inclusion validation?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, rspec-rails, rspec3

My validation ensures that a required field can only be set to either `A` or `R`:

In Model:

```
validates :status_code, inclusion: { in: %w(A R) }
```

In RSpec, I have the following spec:

```
it { expect(@car).to allow_value("A", "R").for(:status_code) }
it { expect(@car).to_not allow_value(nil, "").for(:status_code) }
```

The first RSpec passes, but I get an error on the second one:

```
Failure/Error: it { expect(@car).to_not allow_value(nil, "").for(:status_code) }
       Expected errors  when status_code is set to "", got no errors
```

What am I missing? I'm using RSpec 3.1.

Answer (score 2):

Built-in validators accept the boolean options `:allow_blank` and `:allow_nil` to control how it should behave when the value is one of those two. Try this:

```
validates :status_code, inclusion: { in: %w(A R), allow_blank: false, allow_nil: false }
```

It'd probably also work to add a presence validator to handle nil and the empty string:

```
validates :status_code, inclusion: { in: %w(A R) }, presence: true
```

Comment: thank you for your feedback! If that's the case of including boolean options in the built-in validator, shouldn't my model validator include `allow_blank: false, allow_nil: false` for "consistency" (though including these are superfluous); or, if I do include `allow_blank: false, allow_nil: false`, the validation basically becomes benign because of `inclusion`. Something seems amiss. I look forward to your response.

Comment: Updated with another possible solution.

Comment: Thanks Jimmy. Neither validates work. I think it's an Rspec bug. If I `rails c` then `c = Car.first` then `c.status_code = ''` then `c.valid?` then `c.errors.full_messages` and I get `["Status code is not included in the list"]`